# Compare data within an interval and draw rectangles accordingly

Tags: javascript

I have an interval array like below:

```
var interval = [[1], [1,3], [3,5], [5,7], [7,9], [9]];
```

I want to compare an input value say 1.5 with in the interval, and create an array drawData = [0,1,0,0,0]. To do this, i'm using a if loop like below:

```
            if(attr.freq < interval[0]){
                freqData = [0,0,0,0,0];
            }
            if(attr.freq >= interval[1][0] && attr.freq < interval[1][1]){
                freqData = [1,0,0,0,0];
            }
            if(attr.freq >= interval[2][0] && attr.freq < interval[2][1]){
                freqData = [1,1,0,0,0];
            }
            if(attr.freq >= interval[3][0] && attr.freq < interval[3][1]){
                freqData = [1,1,1,0,0];
            }
            if(attr.freq >= interval[4][0] && attr.freq < interval[4][1]){
                freqData = [1,1,1,1,0];
            }
            if(attr.freq >= interval[5]){
                freqData = [1,1,1,1,1];
            }
```

but the interval may change and I also want to know if there is a better way to to compare within the intervals.

Comment: What's your ultimate goal? To create a bar chart? If so, this looks like a roundabout way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be rewritten using a single map statement.

We just have normalize the data by making the first and last intervals consistent with the other intervals, which are defined by two points.  We use `Infinity` to do this.

The final solution will work with an arbitrary number of test intervals.

Rewrite:

```
function inIntervals(val, intervals) {
  var intervals = intervals.slice(0),    // this makes a copy, so we don't disturb the original array
      last      = intervals.length - 1;

  intervals[0]    = [-Infinity      , intervals[0]];  // here we normalize the first and last intervals
  intervals[last] = [intervals[last], Infinity    ];

  return intervals.map(x => val >= x[0] && val < x[1] ? 1 : 0)
}

var test = [[1], [1,3], [3,5], [5,7], [7,9], [9]];
console.log(inIntervals(1.5, test)); 
// [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

### Update

To transform from a single element array to the format in your example:

```
x = [1,3,5,7,9]
var first = [x[0]];
x = x.map((x,i,a) => a[i+1] === undefined ? [x] : [x, a[i+1]])
x = [first].concat(x);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  if the interval is [1,3,5,7,9] then does map function still works?

Comment: My answer assumes an array of intervals as in your example, where each interval is defined by 2 points (a start and end) -- with the exception of the first and last array elements, which are assumed to be single points (so we have to normalize them).

Comment: Yes, I understand that. so if the array has single entries such as [1,3,5,7,9] then how does interval less than 1 and between 1 and 3 work ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.  The code would need to be changed completely to handle input which was just an array of single numbers.  It's not hard, it just becomes a different question.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks but could you please help me with the new array. I'm working with that and not able to get the solution.

Comment: See my update above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36531/discussion-between-anu-and-jonah).